# VHDL mux 8:1 error in test bench

Tags: vhdl

it is 8x1mux vhdl program 
main program working with no error,
but in test their is some signal i,s ,y are shows error 
and tell i,s,y are already declared.

[image: test bench]

error in test bench

[image]

Comment: Example code should be a [Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Pictures deny others the benefit of search performed on your question. Note in your [Modelsim 10.1c](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hesmaeil/teaching/cs3220/01-2014fa/doc/modelsim/ModelSim_Reference_Manual_v10.1c.pdf) (P.295) you can type verror 1294 at the Transcript or shell prompt and the first sentence tells you "Two declarations that occur immediately within the same declarative region must not be homographs, unless exactly one of them is the declaration of a predefined operation."

Answer (score 3):

The code says:

```
...
entity mux8x1_t is
end mux8x1_t;

architecture mux8x1_t_a of mux8x1 is
  component mux8x1
...
```

So the `architecture` is not for the just declared `entity` as is probably the intention, another architecture for the `mux8x1`, and since the `mux8x1` has ports named `i`, `s`, and `y`, the signals named `i`, `s`, and `y` in the architecture make the compile generate the error.

The `architecture` part should be changed to:

```
architecture mux8x1_t_a of mux8x1_t is
```

For the error `near "=": syntax error`, change `;=` to `:=`.